# Convert a time-only string such as "6:02PM" to a datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime

I have an input that is given in %I:%M%p (ex. "6:02PM").
I'm trying to input into this code to find the difference between now and then:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.now()
then = "6:02PM"
tdelta = now - then
```

Comment: How many times as this operation done? If not tens of thousands of times (or more) in a short period of time, consider *not worrying* about "most efficient way possible", but focus on "clean tidy code" .. and remove such language from the title of the post (as it is ambiguous and/or misleading and/or not needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
then = dt.datetime.combine(now, dt.datetime.strptime("6:02PM", "%I:%M%p").time())
print(then)
# 2012-08-26 18:02:00

tdelta = now - then
print(tdelta)
# -1 day, 20:53:25.190721
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I assume 'import x as y' means that you can reference it as dt in the script. Why the need for dt.datetime then? Wouldn't it be redundant? Or does it have to do with that weird caveat where datetime also has an internal function called datetime?

Comment: Yes, `datetime` is the name of a module, and inside that module is a class which is also called `datetime`. Since I import the module as `dt`, the class is referenced as `dt.datetime`.